# How to consume SalesForce Webservice from .net

Tags: .net, salesforce

I'm trying to consume a SalesForce webservice from .net. I'm really new to SalesForce and don't have much idea about it. If anyone can help me out with a step by step process how to do it that would be very helpful. Below is steps I've done and I'm not sure what I have missed. Please help.

1. SalesForce WebService Code:

   `global class SampleWebService

   {

       webservice static String sayHello(String Name)

       {

           return 'Hello ' + Name + ', welcome to Salesforce WebService.';

       }

   }`
2. Generated the WSDL file.
3. Created .net project and added the web reference of that wsdl.
4. C# code:

   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   namespace SalesForceWebService
   {
       public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
           SalesForceService.SampleWebServiceService objService = new        SalesForceService.SampleWebServiceService();

   ```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
       {  
           lblHello.Text = objService.sayHello("ABC");  
       }  
   }
   ```

   }`

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps I performed for connecting Salesforce using Enterprise WSDL

1. Generate Enterprise WSDL in your salesforce environment as follows
   Setup --> Develop --> API  --> Generate Enterprise WSDL.
   Save that webpage as XML.
2. In Visual studio, right click on References of your project in Solution Explorer, and add the saved XML file as a service reference to the project.
3. Similar way generate WSDL for your apex class also. And attach it as a service reference to the project. (If you exposed any apex class as a webservice, otherwise ingore this step)
4. Start writing Code.

In this program, i'm trying to call a webservice method written in Apex, 
which gets the user object based on unique Id and updates a field.

```
    using ConsoleApplication1.Salesforce;
    using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    class Program
    {
        public static SforceService binding;
        public static ConsoleApplication1.ApexServiceName.ApexClassService classBinding;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            binding = new SforceService();
            LoginResult lr = null;
            binding.Timeout = 120 * 60000;
            try
            {
                lr = binding.login(username,password);
                Console.WriteLine("login success");
            }
            catch (SoapException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

    classBinding = new ConsoleApplication1.ApexServiceName.YOUR_APEXCLASS_NAME();
    binding.Url = lr.serverUrl; //I1
    binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader(); 
    binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;  //I2
    classBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new ConsoleApplication1.ApexClassService.SessionHeader();
    classBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;
    ConsoleApplication1.ApexServiceName.User Appusr = classBinding.getUserById("1234567");  //I3
    Appusr.FirstName = "MurthyFYI"; //I4
    Boolean? result = classBinding.updateUser(Appusr); //I3
    binding.logout();
    }
    }
    }
```

I1) The login results contain the endpoint of the virtual server instance that is servicing your organization. Set the URL of the binding to this endpoint.

I2) Get the session ID from the login result and set it for the session header   that will be used for all subsequent calls.

I3) Call a webservice method of Apex class for which you have generated the WSDL.

I4) Update a field on user object.

For more information you can refer to the post in my blog @ http://murthyvvr.blogspot.in/2013/11/calling-salesforce-webservice-from-c.html
I hope this helps.